# In Ruby on Rails, what does authenticate_with_http_basic do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Restful Authentication uses `authenticate_with_http_basic`, but a search on the net can find many pages with no description.  On the official http://api.rubyonrails.org/, it can also be found, except again there is no description, no comment, no spec.

What does it do?  it seems to be able to use a `login_name` and `password` from an HTTP request and then they can be compared to the `login_name` and `encrypted_password` in the `users` table... but is that the case, why aren't there even a 1-line description?

Answer (score 26):

This method allows you to implement basic http authentication (the kind where a little dialog box pops up asking for a username and password). It's generally a great way to limit access to a development site or admin area. For example:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Administration') do |username, password|
      username == 'admin' && password == 'password'
    end
  end
end
```

This function will either make a request for the basic http authentication username and password, or after it has been entered, it will actually check if the authentication was correct. In other words this function will either call [authenticate_with_http_basic](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic/ControllerMethods/authenticate_with_http_basic) or it will call [request_http_basic_authentication](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic/ControllerMethods/request_http_basic_authentication). You can read more about it and see more examples [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic/ControllerMethods/authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic). You'll generally call authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic instead of calling authenticate_with_http_basic or request_http_basic_authentication, since the former function will all the appropriate of the latter functions.

P.S: authenticate_with_http_basic does not use POST variables, it uses header information to get the username and password (request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']). You can view more information about the authorization function [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic/authorization).

Comment: does `authenticate_with_http_basic` extract from the POST variables `username` and `password` and that's it?  What is the most basic description?

Comment: I added this to my post as well. In short it does not use POST variables, it uses request.env data from the request header.

Comment: In what situation is the username and password in HTTP header?  the log in form (`/session/new` or `/login`) POST to `/session` and the post variable is like: `authenticity_token=TrtiGrt8CcDl9DiVbZLA6Yi24g%2FQ6qazMtOgwlJqpjc%3D&login=foo&password=123123&remember_me=1&commit=Log+in` so I thought the user log in is usually by POST variables?

Comment: Yeah, but http basic authentication is different. You don't use a login form to authenticate, you use a popup or pass the variables in the URL like this: http://username:password@www.example.com. POST authentication and BASIC HTTP authentication are entirely different.

Comment: Also it should be noted that Basic Auth is extremely weak, basically plaintext. If one absolutely has to use it, better make sure that you only accept HTTPS in the concerned controller.

Comment: if you do anything more complicated with roles, etc. using `authenticate_with_http_basic` and `request_http_basic_authentication` is IMO more useful.

Answer (score 11):

Some details that would have saved me time if I could read them anywhere.

I fiddled with it. `authenticate_with_http_basic` just reads basic-auth user/pass from request and executes inner block when such info is present in the request.
If no auth is sent by client, it returns `nil`. Otherwise it returns whatever the block evaluates to.

So you can use return value to decide whether to do `request_http_basic_authentication`, return 403 forbidden or render content.

FYI, if you are running this from a method registered as a `before_action` hook, I noticed that return value of that method is disregarded. In case method `rendered` something or `redirected`, the controller action is not executed. If the method does not `render` or `redirect`, then the controller action is executed.

HTH (talking about Rails 5 to be clear)

Comment: > just reads basic-auth user/pass from request and executes inner block when such info is present in the request.

What format does that request need to be?

Comment: @Trip, search for Basic HTTP Auth. Complete specification you can find at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617 .