# Authenticate_with_http_basic block not executed

Tags: ruby, kubernetes, ruby-on-rails-5

I am observing some weird behavior in my Rails 5.2 app where the basic authentication portion is skipped and is always falsey.

This code runs perfectly fine under local dev environment but `authenticate_with_http_basic` block is never hit under a kubernetes deployment.

The kubernetes app deployment is fronted by a nginx proxy

```rb
     class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
       before_action :authenticate

       def authenticate
         if _valid_credentials?
           # never gets to this part
           true
         else
           # enters the else block
           request_http_basic_authentication
        end
      end

      def _valid_credentials?
        Rails.logger.debug("Function is entered")

        authenticate_with_http_basic do |username, password|
          cred = "#{username}|#{password}"
          # Nothing is printed with Rails.logger.debug
          Rails.logger.debug("Received credentials: #{cred}")
          # Running rails console reveals the correct ::Configuration.credentials
          SecureCompare.compare(cred, ::Configuration.credentials)
        end
      end
    end
```

kubernetes logs:

```
nginx xxx.xxx.xx.xx 0.004 0.002930 - test_user [18/Jun/2019:20:11:26 +0000]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 38 "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3829.0 Safari/537.36" b9af3f83-b2b8-43e1-bee7-1603f5ada6c2 -
app-deployment-name Processing by XXXController#index as HTML
app-deployment-name Function is entered
app-deployment-name Filter chain halted as :authenticate rendered or redirected
app-deployment-name Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Any idea or suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: its expected behaviour if you dont pass basic auth headers

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the tip! Can you expand on that?

Comment: Check out [`this SO answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39640325/4950680) and make sure you pass `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l` header where `QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l` is a base-64 encoded ASCII string in format `username:password`

Comment: My browser is sending an `Authorization: Basic XXX` header to the endpoint (to nginx at least). Maybe nginx is not doing a good job forwarding. Is there a way to print the received header in the `authenticate` method to confirm that the header is there?

Comment: `request.headers["Authorization"]`, `request.headers["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]` or just `request.headers` to get hash with all headers of the request. I would just request backend directly via curl

Comment: Thanks for the help Martin! it turns out to be Nginx that stripped the Authentication header...